# Upload a file to AWS S3 using node js and Postman

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS,and trying to figure out how to upload a file using the AWS S3 API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html), which is incorporated in my own api.

I can create a bucket, and get a list of all the buckets- however I am struggling with a file upload.

This is by code:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var params = {
        Bucket: req.body.bucketName,
        Key: req.body.key,
        Body: req.body.body
    }
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        } else {
            res.json(data)
        }
    })
})
```

So when I run my server, I try to make a post request using postman to `localhost:8080/upload` with the following: attaching a file, and the key and body - but I think I do this part wrong.
[image: postman view]

And I also attach the file:

[image]

**Question is:**

Do I correctly understand the following- `Bucket` = the bucket name I want to upload to, `Key` = the file name, `Body` = the file contents?

If yes, how do I get this to upload to S3 bucket, as with the current code I get a file added to s3 called '`text.txt`' with the contents '`heello`' rather than my '`test.txt`' file.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to upload a file correct? So you should use a multipart/form-data content-type, and in body you can point to your file buffer.

In my case, I use with swagger:

```
upload: (req, res) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key: req.swagger.params.file.value.originalname,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Body: req.swagger.params.file.value.buffer
  };

  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error uploading image: ', err);
      res.status(500).json().end();
    } else {
      res.status(200).json('File is uploaded').end();
    }
  })
}
```